# Projeção geostacionária do cartopy produz dados deslocados

Tags: python, geolocalização

Ola!

Eu estou tentando plotar uns dados de um satélite geoestacionário (MSG-SEVIRI) usando a projeção ccrs.Geostationary do cartopy. O formato dos dados é .grb. Contudo, meu código esta gerando um resultado errado. Os dados parecem estar deslocados em relacao ao mapa.

Segue abaixo, meu codigo:

```
    import pygrib
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from pyresample import geometry
    from pyresample import create_area_def
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs
    from numpy import unravel_index
    
    grbs=pygrib.open('MSG4-SEVI-MSGAESE-0100-0100-20180228000000.000000000Z-20180228001825- 
    1415948.grb')
    
    grb = grbs.select(name='Aerosol optical thickness at 0.635 um')[0]
    maxt = grb.values
    #lats, lons = grb.latlons()
    
    lon=np.linspace(float(67.5), float(-67.5), len(maxt))
    lat=np.linspace(float(-67.5), float(67.5), len(maxt))
    ## OS valores -67.5 and 67.5 values eu peguei aqui: 
     https://navigator.eumetsat.int/product/EO:EUM:DAT:MSG:AES

    a, b = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
       
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    ax=plt.axes(projection= ccrs.Geostationary(satellite_height=35786000))
    ax.set_global()
    ax.coastlines()
    ax.contourf(a, b, maxt, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())  
    plt.show()
```

E o resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebem que o contorno dos dados nao bate com as bordas dos países?  Isso é bem visível se olharmos na parte inferior da imagem, no sul do continente Africano.

Alguém sabe como eu consigo arrumar isso?